# Need help to plot Monthly Magic Trend indicator on daily chart

Tags: pine-script

Need help to plot Monthly Magic Trend indicator on daily chart. Though Monthly chart on monthly timeframe is smooth without multiple reversals to red and green but when trying to plotted this monthly indicator on Daily timeframe then see lot of reversals in red and green. Magic trend indicator use CCI function for calculation. Any help is appreciated. I want to plot monthly chat on daily timeframe exactly i see monthly chart i see in monthly timframe. Here is my code

```
//@version=2
study("Trend Magic PS Multiple",overlay=true)

MTmon = input(true, title="Monthly")
MTwek = input(false, title="Weekly")
MTdai = input(false, title="Daily")

//Monthly

CCI = input(25)
ATR = input(5)
MultiplierM=input(4,title='ATR Multiplier Monthly')
MultiplierW=input(3,title='ATR Multiplier Weekly')
MultiplierD=input(0,title='ATR Multiplier Daily')
original=input(true,title='original coloring')
//thisCCI = security(tickerid, "M", close)

// if (MTmon == true) 
thisCCI = cci(security(tickerid, "M", close), CCI)
lastCCI = nz(thisCCI[1])
bufferDn= high + MultiplierM * sma(tr,ATR)
bufferUp= low - MultiplierM * sma(tr,ATR)
if (thisCCI >= 0 and lastCCI < 0) 
    bufferUp := bufferDn[1]
if (thisCCI <= 0 and lastCCI > 0) 
    bufferDn := bufferUp[1]

if (thisCCI >= 0)
    if (bufferUp < bufferUp[1])
        bufferUp := bufferUp[1]
else
    if (thisCCI <= 0)
        if (bufferDn > bufferDn[1])
            bufferDn := bufferDn[1]

x=thisCCI >= 0 ?bufferUp:thisCCI <= 0 ?bufferDn:x[1]
swap=x>x[1]?1:x<x[1]?-1:swap[1]
swap2=swap==1?lime:red
swap3=thisCCI >=0 ?lime:red
swap4=original?swap3:swap2


plot(MTmon and x ? x : na, title="Monthly", color=swap4,transp=0,linewidth=3)


// if MTwek == true 

thisCCIw = cci(security(tickerid, "W", close), CCI)
lastCCIw = nz(thisCCIw[1])
bufferDnw= high + MultiplierW * sma(tr,ATR)
bufferUpw= low - MultiplierW * sma(tr,ATR)
if (thisCCIw >= 0 and lastCCIw < 0) 
    bufferUpw := bufferDnw[1]
if (thisCCIw <= 0 and lastCCIw > 0) 
    bufferDnw := bufferUpw[1]

if (thisCCIw >= 0)
    if (bufferUpw < bufferUpw[1])
        bufferUpw := bufferUpw[1]
else
    if (thisCCIw <= 0)
        if (bufferDnw > bufferDnw[1])
            bufferDnw := bufferDnw[1]

xw=thisCCIw >= 0 ?bufferUpw:thisCCIw <= 0 ?bufferDnw:xw[1]
swapw=xw>xw[1]?1:xw<xw[1]?-1:swapw[1]
swap2w=swapw==1?lime:red
swap3w=thisCCIw >=0 ?lime:red
swap4w=original?swap3w:swap2w

// plot(xw,color=swap4w,transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(MTwek and xw ? xw : na, title="Weekly", color=swap4w,transp=0,linewidth=3)

// if MTdai == true

thisCCId = cci(security(tickerid, "D", close), CCI)
lastCCId = nz(thisCCId[1])
bufferDnd= high + MultiplierD * sma(tr,ATR)
bufferUpd= low - MultiplierD * sma(tr,ATR)
if (thisCCId >= 0 and lastCCId < 0) 
    bufferUpd := bufferDnd[1]
if (thisCCId <= 0 and lastCCId > 0) 
    bufferDnd := bufferUpd[1]

if (thisCCId >= 0)
    if (bufferUpd < bufferUpd[1])
        bufferUpd := bufferUpd[1]
else
    if (thisCCId <= 0)
        if (bufferDnd > bufferDnd[1])
            bufferDnd := bufferDnd[1]

xd=thisCCId >= 0 ?bufferUpd:thisCCId <= 0 ?bufferDnd:xd[1]
swapd=xd>xd[1]?1:xd<xd[1]?-1:swapd[1]
swap2d=swapd==1?lime:red
swap3d=thisCCId >=0 ?lime:red
swap4d=original?swap3d:swap2d

// plot(xd,color=swap4d,transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(MTdai and xd ? xd : na, title="Daily", color=swap4d,transp=0,linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script requires a port to v3 at the minimum because of its current use of `security()` which will cause lookahead bias in v2, and may also require changes to logic.